# Outlook Web Add-on(Office-JS) ui-less get bootstrap token outlook for Windows

Tags: oauth-2.0, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

i am trying to get an outlook add-on with autorun(ui-less) that uses the bootstraptoken to login to the backend of our application. On the web our application is fine. But on Windows for desktop the getAccessToken() is not available when running ui-less.

i cannot figure out how to get the authentication running  on a ui-less application.

Comment: What options do you pass to the `getAccessToken` method?

Comment: at the moment none.

Comment: Try to to pass the argument for retrieving the token silently.

Answer (score 0):

getAccessToken() is not supported yet on the LaunchEvent Extension Points (i.e. auto running add-ins OnNewMailCompose).

Comment: We have fixed this bug.
For the Semi-Annual Channel, the fix should be available in build 16.0.14326.20258 or later.
For all other channels, the fix should be available in build 16.0.14425.10000 or later.

When an updated build is available depends on the release channel a customer is on.